# Can I define which shard to snapshot?

Tags: elasticsearch

The default setting of snapshot seems creating snapshots for all shards of an index. Can users define which shard to snapshot?

I found creating snapshots can make system busy, and was wondering if I can create snapshot for each shard one by one given some interval times, so the system may not be overloaded for too long.

Answer (score 1):

No, snapshots work at index level. You can define which indices to snapshot.

Snapshots are incremental and shouldn't ideally impact read/ index operation. That being said it does cause some load on the cluster during snapshot process as it reads indices being snapshotted.